# How to render input value in Volt Phalcon?

Tags: php, forms, phalcon, volt, phalcon-orm

I'm trying to get value of a form field but don't know what function is used for this?

```
 {{ MyForm.render("first_name") }}
```

I want to render only `first_name` value not the whole input tag.

FORM:

```
class EbEvaluationForm extends CxAdminBaseForm {

    public function initialize() {

        // set rules object for jQuery Validation
        $this->setClientRulesFromArray(array(
            'date_started' => array('required' => true),
            'date_ended' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        // Initialize validation error messages so that server and client validation will use same messages.
        $this->setValidateMessagesFromArray(array(
            'date_started' => array('required' => 'Date Started is required'),
            'date_ended' => array('required' => 'Date Ended is required')
        ));

        // Create form fields
        $this->add($this->createHiddenField('id'));
        $this->add($this->createTextField('first_name', 'Name', false));
        $this->add($this->createTextField('last_name', 'Last Name', false));
        $this->add($this->createTextField('email', 'Email', false));
        $this->add($this->createTextField('age', 'Age', false));

        $this->add($this->createTextField('phone', 'Phone', false));
        $this->add($this->createTextField('gender', 'Gender', false));

        $this->add($this->createDateRangePickerField('date_started', 'Date Started', true,true,true));
        $this->add($this->createDateRangePickerField('date_ended', 'Date Ended', true,true,true));
    }


}
```

Volt View:

```
 <section id="widget-edit-cx-record">
            <div class="row">
                <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-blueDark" id="wid-id-1" data-widget-editbutton="false">
                        <header class="edit-new edit" role="heading">
                            <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-edit "></i> </span>
                            <h2 class="edit">Edit Client Data</h2><h2 class="new"> Client Data</h2>
                            <span class="jarviswidget-loader">
                                <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
                            </span>
                        </header>
                        <div id="cx-record-edit-div" role="content">
                            <div class="jarviswidget-editbox"></div>
                            <div class="widget-body no-padding">
                                <div id="cx-record-edit-messages" class="messages">
                                    {# Container for alerts #}
                                </div>
                                <form id="cx-record-edit" class="smart-form" data-edit-allowed="{{ ACL['EDIT'] }}">
                                    {{EbEvaluationForm.render("id")}}
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <section class="col col-6">
                                                <label class="label">{{EbEvaluationForm.getLabel("first_name")}}</label>
                                                <p>
                                                {{ EbEvaluationForm.get('first_name').getValue() }}
                                                </p>

                                            </section>
                                           <section class="col col-6">
                                                 <label class="label">{{EbEvaluationForm.getLabel("last_name")}}</label>
                                                 <p>{{ EbEvaluationForm.get('last_name').getValue() }}</p>
                                           </section>

                                        </div>

                                    </fieldset>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
```

JS file:

```
 // Init the Cx Form
    $EbEditForm.cxForm({
        loadDataUrl: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-admin-get-evaluation-quiz-by-id')?>',
        inputsEnabled: false,
        submitEnabled: false,

        beforeSubmit: function(formData){
            return formData;
        },
        saveSuccess: function(){
            $EbEditForm.cxForm("reset");
            cx.common.data.cxAdminDataTables.EbEvaluation.cxAdminDataTable("reloadAjax");
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like so:

```
{{ form.get('YOUR_ELEMENT_NAME').getValue() }}
```

List of Form Class methods: https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/api/Phalcon_Forms_Form.html

List of Form Element methods: https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.3/api/Phalcon_Forms_Element.html

Comment: Give us more details, what have you tried? Show us your controller/form code. "Not working" is just not serious... :)

Comment: Did you pass `entity` when you initialized the form? Can you add your controller code too?